# Tomcat 7 server not visible in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apache, tomcat

Hi i am new to android and i have installed eclipse and Java EE and also tomcat 7.

The problem is that when i go to windows>preferences>servers>runtime environments>add i am not able to find apache tomcat 7 server there. When i give search and try to add it, it gives me no new server runtime found.

Please can anyone help me find it.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Apache MyFaces Trinidad Tag Support (Optional) SDK 2.2.0.v20090310-53-8-52B6695K3B688x422B2747 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport_sdk.feature.feature.group 2.2.0.v20090310-53-8-52B6695K3B688x422B2747)
  Software currently installed: Apache MyFaces Trinidad Tag Support 2.2.201.v201208241503-20A87w312319352614 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.group 2.2.201.v201208241503-20A87w312319352614)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Apache MyFaces Trinidad Tag Support (Optional) 2.2.0.v20090517-20-7w311A1636 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.jar 2.2.0.v20090517-20-7w311A1636)
    Apache MyFaces Trinidad Tag Support 2.2.201.v201208241503-20A87w312319352614 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.jar 2.2.201.v201208241503-20A87w312319352614)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Apache MyFaces Trinidad Tag Support (Optional) 2.2.0.v20090517-20-7w311A1636 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.group 2.2.0.v20090517-20-7w311A1636)
    To: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.jar [2.2.0.v20090517-20-7w311A1636]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Apache MyFaces Trinidad Tag Support 2.2.201.v201208241503-20A87w312319352614 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.group 2.2.201.v201208241503-20A87w312319352614)
    To: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.jar [2.2.201.v201208241503-20A87w312319352614]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Apache MyFaces Trinidad Tag Support (Optional) SDK 2.2.0.v20090310-53-8-52B6695K3B688x422B2747 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport_sdk.feature.feature.group 2.2.0.v20090310-53-8-52B6695K3B688x422B2747)
    To: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.group [2.2.0.v20090517-20-7w311A1636]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual Update your existing installation of Eclipse:

```
Download the applicable WTP source package to your desktop
Shutdown Eclipse
Extract the package to your Eclipse installation directory
Startup Eclipse. (WTP is now available)
```

Comment: where in installation directory should i put it?

Comment: Extract the package to your Eclipse installation directory

Comment: no error i copied the wtp to installation folder but wen i start eclipse cant see apache in servers or in preferences.

Comment: r u using eclipse java EE developer

Answer (score 1):

Preferences option shows all the list of servers for which Eclipse has adapters.

In the add window look for the link "**Download additional server adapters**" at the top. Click that and then download adapters for tomcat 7.

Pls check this link for same : http://besthowtodo.com/blog/2010/05/how-to-configure-tomcat-with-eclipse.html

Also you can consider upgrading your **Eclipse** . That may also solve the problem.

Comment: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Apache MyFaces Trinidad Tag Support (Optional) SDK 2.2.0.v20090310-53-8-52B6695K3B688x422B2747 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport_sdk.feature.feature.group 2.2.0.v20090310-53-8-52B6695K3B688x422B2747)

Comment: it is showing the following error when i do download additional server adapters.

Answer (score 1):

try this way..

get "Eclipse for Java EE developers". Note the extra "EE". This includes among others the Web Tools Platform with among others a lot of server plugins with among others the one for Apache Tomcat 5.x. It's also logically; JSP/Servlet is part of the Java EE API.

check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOkN5IPoJVs&playnext_from=TL&videos=rVnITzSU2Z8)

check this:

Help > Install New Software.

Select "Eclipse Web Tools Platform [Repository](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates)" from the "Work with" drop-down.
    Select "Web Tools Platform (WTP)" and "Project Provided Components".

Complete all the installation steps and restart Eclipse. You'll see a bunch of servers

when you try to add a server runtime environment.

Comment: yo r a life saver man i never knew ppl will help so much in stackoverflow.. i thought yo'll b bored of my questions now

Comment: jayant and i am developing an app which has a login screen for that i have a database in mysql and it can only b connected to android app using php and all so i need this server to work man and its pissing me off now

Comment: and i tried the steps in that video its giving no new server runtimes found...:(